# Payable Invoice Capturing OR extracting automation

Tags: c#, ocr, capture, invoices, iris-recognition

I am creating a desktop/winform application that reads tif/pdf payable invoices and extract all the invoice information to store into database.

I can read the standard barcodes(QR Code, Code39 etc), and some of the payable invoice' standard fields(Invoice Date, Company Name, Address) with OCR (ocr specific region of image) but unable to capture Line items, amount correctly.

I extract information in two phases:
 1. Read specific regions based on the template(user mapped region
    for specific fields)
 2. OCR whole page and search for payable
    invoice standard field names and values

I have idea about following 3 approaches:
 1. Create a Template for one type of Invoice and process all invoices.
 2. Nural network based engine which need to be trained with sample data to work it based on patterns.
 3. Form processing, a kind of OMR. The OCR to look at exact same coordinates where fields were placed on form(during form desing)

**Question:**
How to extact payable invoice using OCR or some inteligent reader?
Primarily I look for some algorithem (C# + OCR engine)/ philoshpy of payable invoice capturing but reference to some SDK with same feature or solid kind of commercial product would be helpfull too.

I googled and found Abbyy FlexiCapture Engine, IRIS Capture & Extract somewhat promissing but mostly are based on templates, or training. They claim that no template or training required but nothing looks 100 auto capture.

Kindly refere some product (at least with free trial), SDK  or Example/sample.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I had mentioned what I have done. (used zonal ocr technique to extract data on predefined regions). but I dont have idea how to extract unstructured data and tables. my first question is "Primarily I look for some algorithem (C# + OCR engine)/ philoshpy of payable invoice capturing". asking for recommend or find tool was last option, since there is much help available for this domain.

Comment: I answered similar questions here before, trying to help by giving specific product recommendations from my own hand-on experience, but Admins/Moderators butchered my answered and removed useful information, which made it discouraging to spend time here to try to help others.  Anyway, a good start is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362926/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-in-ocr-of-bank-statements-in-net Let me know if you have any more specific questions.

Comment: "They claim that no template or training required but nothing looks 100 auto capture"  - correct, today there are some 'pre-baked' templates that make it seem as if no templates are required for simple scenarios, but to achieve high-accuracy in identification and recognition (no one even talks about 100% unless you have limited variations) some template-based work must be used.

Comment: Hi Ilya Evdonikov, the link you posted link to a remove answer, could you point me where can I start looking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did R&D and concluded that: There is no specialized SDK for invoice Capture that can automate it 95-100%. Only there are OCR/ICR and Imaging SDKs which can help to convert images into text/readable documents but rest of capturing/data extraction is solely based on custom search algorithems( as [ilya-evdokimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653904/ilya-evdokimov) mentioned above, you need mixup of steps(zonal ocr, full text ocr and then intelligent data extraction). I had studied some of very popluar products but they just claim auto capture but ultimately they just pul the standard invoice fields automatically but rest of work is same either zonal ocr or manual. This is what I suggest but there are many more improvement depending on the natuture applicaiton:

1. Store the key field(e.g VAT# information for customers in database/xml file
2. Do full page OCR, find key field, match to the customers list and identitfy/classify the type of document/image.
3. Once document type (Invoice payable/recieveable etc) is identified then look for standard fields
4. Allow user to create pre-defined templates for each type of document for each company(the sender of invoices).
5. Compare the results of both algo (full text ocr and zonal) keep the one with better accuracy.

Answer (score 9):

Of course, by 2018 the situation improved a bit. Let me recapitulate the main approaches today:

- Still a raw OCR engine (tesseract, Abbyy, Google OCR etc.) and regexes (this may still work just fine for some very limited use-cases)
- **[Abbyy FlexiCapture Engine](https://www.abbyy.com/en-ee/data-capture-sdk/)** - still going strong, but still based on templates, if you are willing to define one new template for each specific invoice format
- **[Rossum Elis](https://rossum.ai/rir)** (invoices), **[TagGun](https://www.taggun.io/)** (receipts), ... - APIs based on pre-trained machine learning models, i.e. usable and working immediately, with free monthly volumes
- **[LucidTech](https://lucidtech.io/invoice.html)**, **[Itemize](https://www.itemize.com/api/)**, ... - less accessible APIs with a similar functionality (you need to go through a demo and sales process)
- **[Datamolino](https://www.datamolino.com/api)**, **[CloudFactory](https://info.cloudfactory.com/transcription%E2%80%8E)**, ... - APIs with humans behind the scenes performing the data transcription manually (different latency, pricing and accuracy structure)

Answer (score 2):

After more R&D (*) now there now actually are specialized SDKs with APIs:

First - for starters, there is demo at https://rossum.ai/developers

The whole extraction process can now be automated with API (https://docs.api.rossum.ai/) like this:

to upload an invoice:

```
invoice_file=$1
endpoint='https://all.rir.rossum.ai'
curl -H "Authorization: secret_key $ELIS_API_KEY" -X POST -F file="@$invoice_file;type=application/pdf" $endpoint/document
```

to download the results:

```
invoice_id=$1
endpoint='https://all.rir.rossum.ai'
curl -H "Authorization: secret_key $ELIS_API_KEY" $endpoint/document/$invoice_id
```

These bash examples are from https://github.com/rossumai/elis-client-examples/

(* to add, the API is a direct consequence of my own R&D work *in the company* ;) )